# How can I use Dynamic Linq to project sub collections?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I know how to get [Dynamic Linq](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) to project sub (non-collection) objects, e.g.

```
"new(new(CustomerStat.ID) as CustomerStat)", where CustomerStat is a non-collection object.
```

I'd like to do the something similar with collections, e.g.
`"new(LocationId, new(Employees.Select(FirstName)) as Employees)"`, which would return a projected list of locations, with sublists of employees, containing just their first name.

Or in other words, I'd like the DynamicLinq version of the following:

```
  var locations = (new CompanyContext().Locations.
    Select(l => new {l.ID, Emps = l.Employees.Select(e=>e.FirstName)}));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up having to modify DynamicLinq to support this feature.

We've made a [pull request](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/pull/21) with the new feature.  Code can be found [here](https://github.com/giometrix/System.Linq.Dynamic/).